# What is this "/string" file CMake is failing on?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

Using Visual Studio Code, I am getting the following odd error when running CMake:

```
[main] Building folder: CMake-test 
[main] Configuring folder: CMake-test 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -Dcmake.sourceDirectory:STRING=CMake -Dcmake.generator:STRING=Ninja -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -C c:\Devo\CMake-test\string -Hc:/Devo/CMake-test -Bc:/Devo/CMake-test/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] loading initial cache file c:\Devo\CMake-test\string
[cmake] CMake Error: Error processing file: C:/Devo/CMake-test/string
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Devo/CMake-test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(CMAKE_PROJECT VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(CMAKE_PROJECT main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

The main.cpp is just a simple Hello World...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

I've tried different kits, different builds, different generators, "Delete cache and Reconfigure," and still no joy. This is happening across all projects, even those that built before with no difficulty. I can't think of anything I might have done differently in the interim.

Comment: You have `-C c:\Devo\CMake-test\string` on your command line. That sets your initial cache. Do you really need that? Is there anything in that folder?

Comment: I kept removing that "\string" and it kept on coming back. The fix from squareskittles worked,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section in your `cmake` command looks suspect:

```
-C c:\Devo\CMake-test\string
```

This loads a script file to pre-populate the CMake cache, but may have been erroneously set. To remove it, you can do the following:

1. Open **Settings** and search for "*cmake cache*" in the search bar.
2. Under **CMake: Cache Init**, click on "*Edit in settings.json*".
3. The **Default Settings** tab should open, locate the `"cmake.cacheInit"` entry, and change it to `null`:

   ```
       "cmake.cacheInit": null,
   ```

Comment: This worked, so thanks! VSCode still insists that it should be "string" there for some reason.